# Azure pipeline unable to deploy via a bicep file and set values for its parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

In my `azure-pipelines.yml` file I am unable to deploy via a bicep file and set values for its parameters.

Here is the start of my bicep file

```
targetScope = 'subscription'
param location string = 'uksouth'
param environmentCode string
```

Here is the task in my `azure-pipelines.yml` file

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: 'MyName(SomeGuid)'
      subscriptionId: 'SomeGuid'
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
      location: '$(location)'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Infrastructure/Main.bicep'
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      useWithoutJSON: true
```

I have tried overriding parameters in 3 different ways, but get an error for each

1. No dashes on names

```
      overrideParameters: 'location $(location) environmentCode $(environmentCode)'
```

```
##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-create-parameter-file for details.
```

2. Single dash on names

```
      overrideParameters: '-location $(location) -environmentCode $(environmentCode)'
```

```
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidTemplate.
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'resourceGroup' at line '1' and column '1182' is not valid: The language expression property 'location' doesn't exist, available properties are 'name, properties'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-functions for usage details.'.
```

3. Two dashes on names

```
      overrideParameters: '--location $(location) --environmentCode $(environmentCode)'
```

```
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidTemplate.
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters '-location, -environmentCode' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported parameters for this template are 'location, environmentCode'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-pass-parameter-values for usage details.'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of actual resources you want to deploy, `deploymentScope` inputs of `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` be profoundly affected by the `targetScope` in `bicep file`.

> Figuring out the scope of your deployment is critical in this problem

I have coded a sample to show **two types** of deployment, one in `resource group level`, the other is `subscription level`

`rg.bicep`

```
// set the target scope for this file
targetScope = 'subscription'

param resourceGroupName string

param location string

resource newRG 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2023-07-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location: location
}

output newRGResourceId string = newRG.id
```

`vnet.bicep`

```
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'

param vnetName string
param location string

resource newVnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-09-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: 'default'
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: '10.0.2.0/24'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

output newVnetResourceId string = newVnet.id
```

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
variables:
- name: subscriptionId
  value: 'xxxx'
- name: resourceGroupName
  value: 'wb-test-111'
- name: location
  value: 'eastus'
- name: vnetName
  value: 'wb-vnet111'

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: create a new resource group
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: DevOpsSub1Connection-Test
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    location: '$(location)'
    csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rg.bicep'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    overrideParameters: >
      -resourceGroupName $(resourceGroupName)
      -location $(location)


- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: create a vnet in existing resource group
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: DevOpsSub1Connection-Test
    subscriptionId: $(subscriptionId)
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
    location: '$(location)'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/vnet.bicep'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    overrideParameters: >
      -vnetName $(vnetName)
      -location $(location)
```

**my result**:

> you should check `rg` deployment in **subscription** and check `vnet` deployment in **resource group** in azure portal

[image]

Comment: Setting the `deploymentScope` to `Subscription` worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended using a [Bicep parameters file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameter-files?tabs=Bicep) to define these parameters and pass the parameters file to the [**`AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines) task using the '**`csmParametersFile`**' option. And use the '**`overrideParameters`**' option to override the values of the specified parameters.

```yaml
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: 'MyName(SomeGuid)'
      subscriptionId: 'SomeGuid'
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
      location: '$(location)'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: 'path/to/Main.bicep'
      csmParametersFile: 'path/to/parameters/file'
      overrideParameters: '-location $(location) -environmentCode $(environmentCode)'
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      useWithoutJSON: true
```

---

In addition, you also can try to use the related [**Azure CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-cli#deployment-scope) commands or [**Azure PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-powershell#deployment-scope) cmdlet to deploy Azure resources with Bicep files. In the pipelines of Azure DevOps, you can use the [**`AzureCLI`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task to run Azure CLI commands or use the [**`AzurePowerShell`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines) task to run the Azure PowerShell cmdlet.

To pass or override the parameters in Bicep files:

- If using **Azure CLI**, you can use the option '**`--parameters`**' with the '**`KEY=VALUE`**' syntax on the commands. For example.

  ```bash
  az deployment group create \
  --resource-group <resource-group-name> \
  --template-file <path-to-bicep> \
  --parameters location='$(location)' environmentCode='$(environmentCode)'
  ```
- If using **`AzurePowerShell`**, you can use the '**`-KEY VALUE`**' syntax on the cmdlet. For example.

  ```
  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> `
  -TemplateFile <path-to-bicep> `
  -location "$(location)" `
  -environmentCode "$(environmentCode)"
  ```

---

Related documents:

- [**Integrate Bicep with Azure Pipelines**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/add-template-to-azure-pipelines?tabs=CLI)

---